# calculate percentage of distinct records depending on its 'status' using stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a table site_level,I need to work on columns named 'market',status, id.
for column market , I want to calculate percentage of id depending on its status as completion or rejection.
id column may have duplicate rows.so i need distinct rows.
Ex. market 'germany' will have several id's with status accepted or rejected.
i want to calculate percentage like (total distinct id for market germany)/ (distinct id with status as accepted for germany)

I need the query result in below format.
market / count__id_accepted / count_id_rejected/ percentage_accepted / percentage_rejected

Comment: Please show what you have done. I guess you have at least managed to get the totals or total distinct? Or do you want us to do your whole assignment?

Comment: BEGIN
set rej = (SELECT count(distinct unique_id) as'unique_id' from site_level where status='rejected' ) ;
set pen = (SELECT count(unique_id) as'unique_id' from site_level where status='to be performed'  group by market) ;
set z=  (select count(distinct unique_id)  from site_level group by market ) ; 
select market,count(distinct unique_id),rej from site_level group by market ;

END
with above statements , i am able to get the distinct count but i can't group by market.
it says subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Please add it to the question. Code in comments is not readable.

Comment: I have reached my question limit, I can not put it there.I kindly resquest you to help me out.

Comment: There is a limit of 6 questions per 24 hours, which should *really* be enough if you try to solve your problem yourself in the mean time. But that limit shouldn't count for editing questions.

Comment: Am I alone in thinking that this question falls far below the standard expected of this forum? <- at least this IS a question !

Comment: i have seen worse questions than this.
i am new to stored procedures, i need to get distinct count group by market and again calculate result and group the result by market.

Comment: GolezTrol...
thank you for your interest.
i tried it on my own in the mean time, and yes, i have a solution now.

Answer (score 0):

select `result1`.`market` AS `market`,count(`result1`.`unique_id`) AS `distinct unique_id`,count(result1.status='accepted' or null) as'count_acc',count(result1.status='accepted' or null)*100/count(result1.unique_id) as 'perc_accepted',count(result1.status='rejected' or null) as 'count_rej',count(result1.status='rejected' or null)*100/count(result1.unique_id) as 'perc_rejected',
count(result1.status='to be performed' or null) as 'count_tbp',count(result1.status='to be performed' or null)*100/count(result1.unique_id) as 'perc_tbp',count(result1.status='incomplete test' or null) as 'count_inco',
count(result1.status='incomplete test' or null)*100/count(result1.unique_id) as 'perc_inco' from `result1`
  group by `result1`.`market`